# Short story where man removes food from spaceship because of cheating wife

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, spaceship

The plot is basically a short story where a maintenance guy figures out his wife is cheating on him and removes the food from a spaceship and it’s not realized until after launch.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any more details you may remember? You've also tagged your question with [tag:time-travel] but the question body makes no mention of this, was this intentional?

Comment: Reminds me of another short story where a guy figures out his wife is cheating, and sabotages the spaceship the wife and lover are going to fly off in. Aside from that, it's almost the complete opposite of the story you described.